# Docker error at higher core counts on a multi core machine

Tags: docker

I am running a Centos Container using docker on a RHEL 65 machine. I am trying to run an MPI application (MILC) on 16 cores. 
My server has 20 cores and 128 GB of memory. 
My application runs fine until 15 cores but fails with the "APPLICATION TERMINATED WITH THE EXIT STRING: Bus error (signal 7)" error when using 16 cores and up. At 16 cores and up these are the messages I see in the logs.

Jul 16 11:29:17 localhost abrt[100668]: Can't open /proc/413/status: No such file or directory

Jul 16 11:29:17 localhost abrt[100669]: Can't open /proc/414/status: No such file or directory

Jul 16 11:29:17 localhost abrt[100670]: Can't open /proc/417/status: No such file or directory

A few details on the container

kernel 2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64

Official centos from docker hub

Started container as

docker run -t -i -c 20 -m 125g --name=test --net=host centos /bin/bash

I would greatly appreciate any and all feedback regarding this. Please do let me know if I can provide any further information.

Regards

Comment: Is it really Docker to blame or is it your MPI app?

Comment: I tried a couple of things to test this.I ran the same application with >16 cores on the Bare metal machine using the same MPI installation and that ran fine. I Recompiled the MPI on the container and I still see the same error.